# How to get X509Certificate from Thales HSM 8000?

Tags: .net, cryptography, rsa, hsm, pkcs#1

I'm building an app connecting to HSM. I want to sign pdf file by this app. I have done this if the HSM has support for PKCS11. However, Thales HSM 8000 is not supported. I wish to take X509Certificate2 from Thales HSM 8000.

I tried to send and receive commands through socket to Thales HSM simulator. I don't have the equipment to test the command to retrieve data (Emulator is Thales 7000 should not support the command to sign).

I hope to get a simple example. Or can you tell me the How to do this. I know this is an unreasonable request. However, because I have only few days to study this problem and have to check on the actual device should be forced to bother you.

Thank you much for reading.

Answer (score 0):

in secure mode use SG Command and select management option then external CSR